# Laravel how to find multiple counts on same field of a table with a join on another table having multiple groupBy

Tags: laravel, query-builder, multiple-tables

I have two tables:

Table-1: `user_invitations`

[user_invitations table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gA8b.png)

| id | user_id | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | upton.ellis@example.com |
| 2 | 1 | glenna13@example.net |

Table-2: `users`

[users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhb1U.png)

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | upton.ellis@example.com |
| 102 | fake@example.net |

I want to select the following and display them in a single overview:

1. Total number of invitation requests sent by a user.
2. Total number of users signed up against each user's invitation by looking into the `users` table

[No. of signups and requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTCul.png)

| User | Total Requests | Total Signups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User A | 5 | 3 |
| User B | 7 | 2 |

I have only 1 choice of using Laravel Builder Query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder and want to fetch the statistics using a single composite query:

```php
    return $request->withOrdering($request->withFilters(
        return query->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as requests'))
        ->orWhere(function ($q) {
            return $q->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(*) as signups'))
                ->join('users', 'user_invitations.email', '=', 'users.email')
                ->groupBy('user_id');
        })
        ->groupBy('user_id')
    );
```

In the end, it only shows the total number of requests. The result from the query inside the orWhere(closure()) is not displaying.

Please let me suggest how the change the query but not using Model:: itself only through the Builder $query being the only choice.

Comment: If users A and B both sent an invitation request to the same invitee, and the invitee signed up, how would you know if the signup is credited to user A or B?

Comment: Already have a check on the invite email, so it remains unique regardless of the user. It becomes already invited for another user.

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. Can you elaborate your no. 2 requirement more?

Comment: If an invited email address is also found in the users table that is counted in total signups through an inviting user.

Comment: Regardless of the structure/flow of the application if someone can suggest a composite query.

Comment: I'm asking because no one could guess how the "total signups" column is made without understanding the structure/flow of the application. I ask again, if users A and B invite the same user C, and user C accepted user A's invitation, how does your database schema represent that user C signed up via user A's invitation, and not user B's?